# Retrieving documents from Vespa at scale

Tags: vespa

I am looking for an overview on what is required and how to connect with Vespa for retrieving indexed data at scale.
i've run stress tests on Vespa document RESTful API and as suggested in documentation, it has an upper bound.

http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-api-guide.html indicates the way forward but assumes a head-start on subject matter.

i can figure

```
com.yahoo.documentapi.messagebus.MessageBusDocumentAccess
```

and related bus creation etc.

```
MessageBusDocumentApiTestCase
```

adds some more to understanding.

package jrt https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/tree/master/jrt and some more resources come to aid but the trail, to humbly accept, is tough to put together :)

The trouble is i can't find, if documented, any guide to clearly explain how to invoke vespa from an external system, or if that's not possible, run an embedded client and how it talks to vespa cluster.

please point me to if such an overview exists.

edit:

```
vespaclient-java/src/main/java/com/yahoo/vespaget/DocumentRetriever.java
```

-- another example. thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate of a question which has already been answered in a github issue: https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/3628

> For feeding to Vespa clusters from external systems which is not part
>   of your Vespa cluster we recommend
>   http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/vespa-http-client.html.
>
> For reading single get operations from Vespa the http RESTful API for
>   GET described in http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-api.html
>   is the best option. The RESTful API for GET is built on top of the
>   http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-api-guide.html which is a
>   low-level api to use on nodes which are part of a Vespa cluster
>   already and have access to configuration like schema and content
>   clusters and number of nodes.